# Magento 1.9X Role Resource Tree customization?

Tags: magento-1.9, role, resources

I want to customize Role Resources module tree that is showing when we add/edit a role.
I found some files that are responsible for this :

1. For Front End(admin) :
   `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/permissions/rolesedit.php`
2. For Backend(Functionality) : (Check this one)
   `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Mage/Block/Permissions/Tab/Rolesedit.php`

Please let me know what I can do, I need to hide some modules from this tree.

Comment: Following may help you to up to some extent http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/restrict-admin-roles-in-magento/

Comment: @Muk, Thanks, But I already checked this. Not working for me. I Done this via just hide  some modules permanently from xml files.

Comment: Do you mean to say you disabled some of the modules?

Comment: @Muk, Yes, Now they will not display anywhere in my admin panel.